# Validation in ASP.NET User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, user-controls

I have an ASP.NET user control in which there are two fields (fromdate and todate) which have RequiredFieldValidators associated with them.  When saving I want to validate if the fromdate and todate are entered.  How do I do that?  I have tried Page.IsValid, but it always returns true.

Comment: What kind of a validator do you use?

Comment: The HTML of your User Control would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

there is some problem in your `usercontrol` required field validator.
If the validation is working properly,if you not entered any value on the control it wont go to `postback`.

Answer (score 0):

The RequiredFieldValidator will obviously tell you if the controls have been populated, providing you have specified a **ControlToValidate** in them.

If you want to check whether they are *valid* dates then you would use the CompareValidator and set the **DataType** to be **Date** and then the **Operator** to **DataTypeCheck**.

You could also use a CompareValidtor to compare the two dates using **ControlToValidate** and **ControlToCompare** properties.